# CoreData: Varying execution times for same query

Tags: swift, core-data, sqlite

I am using CoreData to store about 250.000 rows of data in a table with 35 attributes (all Strings), none of them are indexed at this time. When I launch the application with no other apps running and execute the following query, the fetch execution time differs for multiple launches.

1) `CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.ZBP_Q, COUNT( t0.ZNOF_LAY) FROM ZVEH t0 GROUP BY  t0.ZBP_Q 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.4265s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.4266s for 15 rows.`

2) `CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.ZBP_Q, COUNT( t0.ZNOF_LAY) FROM ZVEH t0 GROUP BY  t0.ZBP_Q 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 9.9614s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 9.9615s for 15 rows.`

First of all, 0.4266s seems like a long time for 15 rows, doesn't it? But why exactly does it take the application about 10 seconds for the exact same query under the exact same conditions for another launch? **And how can I ensure the 0.4266 seconds for every launch?**
It seems like the application randomly either takes a very long time or is quite fast (I'm fine with the 0.4266 seconds).

Comment: Execution time depends on factors like what else the computer is doing, if the database file is cached in memory or has to be read from physical storage, if you have a busy timeout set and another connection has an open transaction, etc. Having an index on the column you're grouping by will help in general.

Comment: And isn't that 0.4266s for scanning 250,000 rows? With 15 in the result?

Comment: You're right about the scanning, my mistake!
Depending on the user input, I have to use the same query for every single attribute in my table, swapping only the GROUP BY and the selected attribute. Therefore, is it also helpful to have an index for every attribute? What disadvantages can I expect if I do so?

Comment: The costs to having lots of indexes are larger file size, and slower inserts and deletions as all the indexes have to be updated.